# Issue with Date format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am currently using SQL Server 2008. I am extracting a column `F254` value from a SQL query where it is returning the date format in `MM/DD/YYYY` (e.g. `8/17/2017`).

I need the output to be in format `YYYYMMDD` (e.g. `20170817`).

Note that the column `F254` is of datatype `char(10)` and I cannot change the datatype.

I have tried below but the getting the needed output

```
  H.F254 AS Original_Date,  --> 8/17/2017
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), H.F254, 111) AS eg1, --> 8/17/2017
  REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), H.F254, 103), '/', '') AS eg2 -->8172017
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), H.F254, 112) AS eg3 --> 8/17/2017
```

I have also checked the following [Date Format](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) but its not working

Comment: Your approach is correct ...Convert is the correct option.

Comment: @GaganSharma i really don't know why its not working

Comment: why the datatype is of char? instead of Datetime ?

Comment: @GaganSharma actually the system retrieve information from other tables and then store it in the table that i am quering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to convert it to a date first!

```
select convert(varchar(10),cast(H.F254 as date),112)
```